# origin of the methods like Object.defineProperty , String.fromCharCode()

Tags: javascript

Can't find proper title for my question.It may be an inapropriate question to post.But i have some question about some methods like `Object.defineProperty()` `String.fromCharCode(str)` etc.I mean all object inherits from `Object.prototype` and strings inherits form `string.prototype`.`Object.prototype` object has properties and methods like object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(), object.prototype.isEnumerable() etc.Similarly string.prototype has string.prototype.split etc methods.Every object inherits from its prototype chain.so we can call them on the object itself like myobj.hasOwnProperty('prop') and mystring.split() etc.

But there are some methods which `takes the object itself as arguments`.Like Object.defineProperty(obj,name,{}) ,Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myobj) and String.fromCharCode().They are not in the prototype object.The methods on prototype object has its origin in Object.prototype.I can track their origin .I tried in the console.I searched in *proto* ,they are nowhere.My question is **what are they and where they come form?**

```
function Animal(){
    //something...
}
console.dir(Animal);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're direct properties of the `Object` object (or the `Array` object in the case of `Array.isArray` and such, or the `Math` object in the case of `Math.min` and such). You can find them in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).

Remember that in JavaScript, functions are objects. So the `Object` function can have properties on it, and like all properties, those properties can refer to (other) function objects. So just like `Object.prototype.toString` is a property referring to the function that handles `toString` for plain objects, `Object.defineProperty` is a property that refers to a function that handles defining a property on the object you pass into it.

Sometimes they're called "static" methods (as opposed to "instance" or "prototype" methods), but that term is more associated with class-based languages and isn't really right for JavaScript. They're just functions, referenced by properties on objects.

Comment: i thought of something like that.. needed an expert opinion :)